Dual of finite reflexive modules
Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be a finite reflexive $A$-module, i.e. the natural map $M\to (M^{\vee})^{\vee}$ is an isomorphism. Can we deduce that the dual $M^{\vee}$ is also finite?

This is for a non-Noetherian $A$ right? Because if $A$ is Noetherian and $M$ is finite, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)=M^\vee$ is always finite.

@walkar Yes, the ring A can be non-Noetherian.
